# How I can catch GET params changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to fire event when url changed from `http://localhost:3000/?foo=bar1` to `http://localhost:3000/?foo=bar2`

I have this code:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(this.props.location.query)
    console.log(nextProps.location.query)
  }
```

But I always get same values in `this.props` and `nextProps`
I founded this [issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2997), but it doesn't have solution

Comment: Where's the code where you actually take the location and pass it as a prop to this component?

Comment: @lux Something like that: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/indapublic/952572853cfbe8b89e671df8794feb4d/raw/3e63425d01f52f77e48dc6643789122917373bec/react-router%2520location

Comment: @lux And you can visit https://jsbin.com/culoxu/edit?js,console,output

Comment: I updated the jsbin: https://jsbin.com/xigesupife/edit?js,console,output     Now, just take the location query and set it on state. And in `componentWillReceiveProps` use nextProps.location to update your `state.location`, or something along these lines.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest using `browserHistory.push('/somePath')` instead of manipulating context.location. `browserHistory` comes with `react-router`

Comment: @lux I need to compare `this.props` and `nextProps`. Just added one line in your example: https://jsbin.com/mozuteyavu/1/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

check this link 
https://jsbin.com/culoxu/edit?js,console,output

use`shouldComponentUpdate(){}`

Comment: do you useshouldComponentUpdate  ?

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` have same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

*It wasn't clear whether you were using `react-router` (and which version?) in your question (the only clue was in the tag). I feel like it would help others if you added that info the question.* Anyway:

Define a `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method as such:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.location.query.foo !== this.props.location.query.foo) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
```

I use the construct above with `react-router` version 3.

Comment: Hm. Tried to implement small demo and it's working with `componentWillReceiveProps`. But not working in my legacy project. Components' versions are same